# Es posible loguearse contra una bbdd, con usuarios que tienen la password encriptada?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, login, java-8, spring-security

Tengo una base de datos, con usuarios dados de alta (donde su campo password, tiene la misma encriptada). Y estoy armando un servicio de autenticacion para que los usuarios dados de alta en dicha tabla puedan loguearse a través de este servicio.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de loguearse, el servicio de seguridad me devuelve: ***Encoded password does not look like BCrypt***

Según me dicen, esto que quiero hacer no se puede realizar, porque no hay forma de leer las passwords encriptadas de la bbdd, esto es asi?

Esta es mi clase de Configuración de Spring Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    /**
     * Singleton para encriptar las passwords de los usuarios
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Se define la autenticacion por base de datos
     * y la lectura/escritura de passwords encriptadas
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    /**
     * Se securizan todos los endpoints del servicio
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

Y esta es la implementacion del servicio UsersDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Carga los usuarios de la base de datos y sus roles
     * al objeto UserDetails standard de Spring Security
     * 
     * @Transactional: 
     *                 Esto iniciara una transaccion de bbdd 
     * mientras dure el metodo loadUserByUsername, permitiendo que 
     * cualquier coleccion diferida se recupere de la bbdd cuando intente usarlos.
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: seguramente el sistema de encriptacion de la password de la base no es el mismo con el que quieres desencriptar tu.

Comment: Y como puedo averiguar el sistema de encriptacion de la base? Gracias.

Comment: si fuera tan facil  no seria tan seguro, no lo se realmente  es que eso funciona con una clave secreta de encriptacion, habría que ver bajo que criterio de encriptacion trabajo el backend-  como das de alta usuarios? si tienes forma de ver el codigo que da de alta usuarios, fácilmente veras el codigo con el que encripta.

Comment: Hola Gustavo,   como ya te comentaron, para hacer reversing de este cifrado de password deberás conocer la implementación de cifrado, si es en bloques, flujo, etc. Ahora si  no tienes forma de ver como se cifro, pero si puedes dar alta usuarios o el usuario si conocer su contraseña.  Cuando el usuario  intente hacer login, tomar  el password, pasarlo  por función de  cifrado y comparar las 2 password cifradas.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias @Ventur y @JJMADEO. Hice lo que me dijeron, y debuggeando el alta de usuario en la app legacy encontre el algoritmo de encriptacion:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder@527c8f3b
SHA-256
false
1
```

Para que funcione solo hizo falta modificar el método ***bCryptPasswordEncoder*** de la clase de configuración ***SecurityConfig*** a:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256");
}
```